# split variable into command option arguments in sh

Tags: shell-script, shell

Can anyone tell me the most efficient way to convert a variable to a repeating -param in a script call? I don't know how to describe it properly, but the examples speak for themselves. At least I hope they do :)

Example1:

```bash
# input
export DOMAINS="domain1.tld,domain2.tld"

# tranform to
./example-script.sh -d "domain1.tld" -d "domain2.tld"
```

Example2 (input is singular):

```bash
# input
export DOMAINS="domain1.tld"

# tranform to
./example-script.sh -d "domain1.tld"
```

[UPDATE]
I'm sorry for not adding this in the first post.

Context I should have added:

- DOMAINS is env variable added to a Docker container
- Container only has `sh` shell, so `zsh` and `bash` specific options won't work.
- Sorry for adding the initial `bash` tag.

Comment: Is there a reason `DOMAINS` is an environment variable (exported)? Usually, if you want to store many _separate things_ in a variable, you use an array, e.g. `domains=(domain1.tld domain2.tld)`.

Comment: Context I should have added:

- `DOMAINS` is env variable added to a Docker container
- Container only has `sh` shell, so `zsh` options won't work.

Thanks for the replies so far! will have to look into them to see what would work given these constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier with `zsh`:

From your scalar variable containing a `,`-separated list:

```
DOMAINS="domain1.tld,domain2.tld"
```

`s`plit on `,` into an array:

```
domains=( ${(s[,])DOMAINS} )
```

*zip* a `opt=( -d )` array with it:

```
opt=( -d )
./example-script.sh ${opt:^^domains}
```

If `./example-script.sh` supports `-ddomain1.tld` in addition to `-d` `domain1.tld`, you can skip the intermediary array and use:

```
./example-script.sh -d$^domains
```

In bash, you could use a loop:

```
IFS=, # split on ,
set -o noglob # disable glob
domains=( $DOMAINS ) # split+glob
args=()
for domain in "${domains[@]}"; do
  args+=( -d "$domain" )
done
./example-script.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Or you could generate code in the shell syntax with:

```
IFS=, # split on ,
set -o noglob # disable glob
domains=( $DOMAINS ) # split+glob
if [ "${#domains[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  printf -v args ' -d %q' "${domains[@]}"
else
  args=
fi
shell_code="./example-script.sh$args"
eval -- "$shell_code"
```

If `./example-script.sh` supports `-ddomain1.tld` in addition to `-d` `domain1.tld`, you could also do:

```
IFS=, # split on ,
set -o noglob # disable glob
domains=( $DOMAINS ) # split+glob
./example-script.sh "${domains[@]/#-d}"
```

Where we prepend `-d` to each element of the `$domains` array.

Standard `sh` doesn't have arrays nor `read -A/-a` and standard `printf` doesn't have `%q` (and the implementations that support it as an extension don't always generate `sh`-compatible quoting), but you could use the first bash approach above and `"$@"` in place of an array:

```
IFS=, # split on ,
set -o noglob # disable glob
set --
for domain in $DOMAINS; do # split+glob
  set -- "$@" -d "$domain"
done
./example-script.sh "$@"
```

Another option is to call `awk` to do the splitting and generate `sh`-compatible code:

```
eval "./example-script.sh$(
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q="'" '
    function shquote(s) {
      gsub(q, q "\\\\" q q, s)
      return q s q
    }
    BEGIN {
      n = split(ENVIRON["DOMAINS"], domains, ",")
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        printf " -d %s", shquote(domains[i])
    }'
)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
domains=( "domain1.tld" "domain2.tld" )
./example-script.sh $(printf -- '-d "%s" ' "${domains[@]}")
```

Comment: Indeed it should, thanks @cas.

Comment: That would pass arguments containing quotes to `./example-script.sh`. You're using split+glob here which is not what you want.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that should result in `./example-script.sh -d '"domain1.tld"' -d '"domain2.tld"'`. Yes, the domains are quoted, but that's what the OP had in the original example. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: and probably better to just use `printf -- '-d %q ' "${domains[@]}"`

Comment: Oops, your answer ended up in my "low quality post" review queue. I think it looks ok, though ;) - you might still consider adding an explanation why the `printf` call will indeed lead to multiple `-d option` statements.

Comment: It seems to me the OP want s the equivalent of that `./example-script.sh -d "domain1.tld" -d "domain2.tld"` shell code to be evaluated, that is for `./example-script.sh` to be called with `-d`, `domain1.tld`, `-d`, `domain2.tld` as arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged with `bash` so here's an array-based solution for that shell:

```
DOMAINS="domain1.tld,domain2.tld"

# Comma separated string to array
IFS=, read -r -a domains <<<"$DOMAINS"

# Array to parameter list
args=()
for domain in "${domains[@]}"; do args+=(-d "$domain"); done
```

You would then interpolate the `"${args[@]}"` list into the resulting command (including the double quotes). For example,

```
./example-script.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: It should be noted that  contrary to split+glob, `IFS=, read -ra domains <<<"$DOMAINS"` (you forgot `-r` byw)  only works for values of `$DOMAINS` that don't contain newline characters. Contrary to  split+glob, it can also not be told to preserve a trailing empty element.

Comment: Good catch around `-r` thank you @StéphaneChazelas. I do appreciate your correctness. The other part I don't think matters here based on the structure of the incoming string, but is also a good reminder to me.